# Implementation of multi-screen layout with toolbar limited to only one portion of the layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, multiscreen

I am trying to create a XML design for android tablet. Please look at the samples I attached [Navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIE3u.png) , [Main-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNzqd.png),
 [Layout-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqHf6.png). I have to implement multi-screen layout with toolbar limited to  only  fragment-1 (ie orange portion in Main-layout) and fragment-2(ie. white portion in Main-layout) should be full screen in the [Main-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNzqd.png), leaving all other layout to have complete toolbar(Example. [Layout-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqHf6.png)). How can i implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nikhil have read my previous comment on your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52177875/7666442

Comment: Hi @AndreyPortnoy. Thanks for your valid time. I am just beginner. What i I requested is a suggestion/solution for which i am not complete aware of, not for a service to code for me. I believe stack is meant for suggestion/solution for the issues :). Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean whether its valid question or not. And am sorry i will try to come back later with question you know. Once again thanks :)

Comment: @NileshRathod once gain thanks. That's why i re-post my question again. I hope my reply is clear about what you questioned me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must be implementing this using one Activity class and two Fragment classes. So, you can achieve this by removing the default action bar from Activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Then, you can create a custom `Toolbar` with tabs in one of the fragments.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks :). If you don't mind do you have any samples for me to refer to. It would be great help. Now what i did is the Main-layout is inside a fragment as i required to implement the navigation drawer.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes for more info

Comment: @Nikhil Implementation of a drawer is very easy. Read about DrawerLayout and NavigationLayout